# How to set vertical scrollbar in jdialog?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea, jscrollbar

i have a jdialog with a jpanel inside it.I have jlabels(pictures) on the jpanel.How can i get a vertical scrollbar in jdialog without using textarea?

Comment: your another questions about same topic, are you think that's is really time to shows your code that display us what did you tried :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be you should try adding your jpanel in JScrollPane so when panel goes beyond limit scroll will be shown.

Comment: After adding scrollpane to jpanel i cannot place the labels the way i wanted.

Comment: Which way do you want your labels? what's the problem you are facing when trying this?

Comment: i want to place the label in the middle of the panel  but the label moves to the extreme left of the panel

Comment: @Hemanth: Change your layout. Depending on your need in this question you should try BorderLayout. Add jlabel to center of it. Don't use group layout.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Harry. You should use [`JScrollPane`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html) and work your way with the different [`ScrollBar Policies`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html#scrollbars). 
See [this tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) on JScrollPane and how to use it.